# Extending Entity Members | WCF Data Service Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I have created another partial class from the Entity

```
namespace Model
{
    public partial class CustomEntity
    {
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string CustomMember { get; set; }
    }
}
```

but the problem is that member is not showing when consuming this entity from a WCF Data Service

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding [DataContract()] attribute to the class and check?